# How can I catch a sec_error_unknown_issuer error in an AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

How can I catch a sec_error_unknown_issuer error in an AJAX call? This is in an extension and thus run with Chrome privileges.

The Error Console shows:

```
mysite.com:443 uses an invalid security certificate.

The certificate is not trusted because no issuer chain was provided.
The certificate expired on 04/30/2012 12:24 AM. The current time is 09/10/2013 06:08 PM.

(Error code: sec_error_unknown_issuer)
```

I would like to display a friendly message rather than having the application fail silently.

Answer (score 2):

`this.channel.status` seems to have all the error codes. The problem is, the status is a number and they don't appear to be documented. `Components.results` contains some, but not all, of these codes and assigns them a constant. Since I couldn't find any documentation, I suppose we have to guess based on the constant, as to what went wrong. The SSL errors aren't in `Components.results` and were found through trial and error.

Here's a function that gets some of the errors and produces a message.

```
// Call this from your AJAX error handler
self.GetAJAXFailureCode(this.channel.status);


self.GetAJAXFailureCode = function(Status){
   var ERROR_CODE,ERROR_MESSAGE;

   // Some, but not all can be found in Components.results.
   // All the other codes appear to be undocumented, and have
   // to be discovered through trial and error (thanks Mozilla.)
   switch(Status){
      case(2153390067): 
         ERROR_CODE = 'sec_error_unknown_issuer';
         ERROR_MESSAGE = 'The certificate was signed by an unknown Certificate Authority (add the CA to FF to fix).';
      break;
      case(2153390069):
         ERROR_CODE = 'sec_error_expired_certificate';
         ERROR_MESSAGE = 'The SSL certificate has expired.';
      break;
      case(2152398879):
         ERROR_CODE = 'NS_ERROR_REDIRECT_LOOP';
         ERROR_MESSAGE = 'You seem to be going in circles!';
      break;    
      case( 2152398864):
         ERROR_CODE = 'NS_ERROR_OFFLINE';
         ERROR_MESSAGE = 'There is no network. There is only XUL.';
      break;
      case( 2152398862):
         ERROR_CODE = 'NS_ERROR_NET_TIMEOUT';
         ERROR_MESSAGE = 'The network connection timed out.';
      break;
      case(2152398878): // This happens when the network cable is unplugged.
         ERROR_CODE = 'NS_ERROR_UNKNOWN_HOST';
         ERROR_MESSAGE = 'Please make sure your network cable is securely fastened, and the network is up. (Unknown Host)';
      break;
      default:
         ERROR_CODE = 'unknown_error';
         ERROR_MESSAGE = 'An error with code '+this.channel.status+' occurred. Good luck wih that.';            
   }
   return [ERROR_CODE,ERROR_MESSAGE];      
}
```